# Is it possible to check Map size in a VisualForce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

For checking a list size in visual force page its 
    `<apex:pageBlockTable ... rendered="{!contacts.size>0}">`

For checking a map size in visual force page ??
    `<apex:pageBlockTable ... rendered="{!contactsMap.size>0}">`

Apex:
    `Map<Id, Contact> contactsMap = new Map<Id, Contact>([Select Id, Name, Phone, Account, Email From Contact Limit 10]);`

I am unable to get the map size in visualforce page, please let me know the correct syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a `Boolean` property in your backend `Apex` to store if the map is empty, and use that for rendered tag:

```java
public boolean getMapIsEmpty() {
  Map<String, String> colorCodes = new Map<String, String>();
  colorCodes.put('Red', 'FF0000');
  colorCodes.put('Blue', '0000A0');

  return colorCodes.size() == 0;
}
```

Vf Code

```
<apex:pageBlockTable ... rendered="{!NOT(mapIsEmpty)}"
```

Comment: Strange sample code and boolean/integer a bit mixed up?

Comment: more compact: `return colorCodes.isEmpty();` - you are returning true if map is non-empty

Comment: thank you @MohithShrivastava  for the suggestions. I figured another simple way by using a Boolean variable in apex - I am setting this var to true if map size is > 0 and false otherwise and then I am using this var in the VF Page.